# Conda Installation Cannot Install Boost, LAPACK or MKL

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, cmake, anaconda, conda

I have a software which has a makefile and it gives the error:

```
-- Could NOT find LAPACK (missing: LAPACK_LIBRARIES) 
-- Could NOT find MKL (missing: MKL_Core_LINK_LIBRARY) 
-- Could NOT find Boost
```

I tried installing them using Conda and the installations went fine.

However the error still persists.

I tried:

```
export LAPACK_LIBRARIES="/home/me/anaconda2/lib"
export LAPACK_LIBRARIES="/home/me/anaconda2/lib"
```

But again the error persist in while running cmake.

How do I resolve the error?

Comment: You have `-devel` packages for lapack and MKL installed too, don't you?

Comment: @Tsyvarev how do i install that?

Comment: Hm, I am not very familiar with conda packaging. When install lapack using Conda, do you have any `.so` files to be installed (*not* in form like `.so.1` but pure `.so` extension)? And do you have header (`.h`) files installed? Where?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is this a CMake build or a regular `make` build?

Comment: @darthbith i am on an Ubuntu server...regular make build, make install

Comment: That doesn't look like a regular Make file... Also, in your question you say that it is a CMake build! Which is correct? Can you provide a link/URL to the software you're trying to build?